# What to do if multiple accounts are ostensibly the same person?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Case in point:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/62182/revisions

shows that [Man](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/45256/man) and [user46417](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/46417/user46417) are one and the same user.

Personally, I'd recommend a deletion of the "unnamed" user with pointing out that multi-usering is discouraged, but I don't know policy on that.

EDIT: Ah, [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) says that accounts *can* be merged, so this now becomes a merge request, unless Man engaged in "sockpuppeteering" (i.e. using user46417 to upvote himself).

EDIT2: The [edit history](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/62352/revisions) of [Difference between repeated poles and non repeated poles?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62352/difference-between-repeated-poles-and-non-repeated-poles) might suggest that also [abjt](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/37462/abtj) and Man are the same person, although it's not *that* conclusive; abjt might simply have been sitting next to Man and overly eagerly tried to specify Man's question and changed directions of the question in the process. I'll simply ask.

EDIT3: OK, this is starting to feel like a conspiracy theory, but [engr](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/39794/engr)'s [Image processing vs signal processing?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62348/image-processing-vs-signal-processing) is, especially in the final sentence, so much like [image processing vs Computer vision?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60834/image-processing-vs-computer-vision) that it defies the feeling of a likely coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me that `Man` and `user46417` are the same.  The system logs IP addresses and registered email addresses and both are very different for each user. I can also see that the two are not acting as "sock puppet" accounts. Again, the system flags cross-support and neither shows any activity like that.

Perhaps they're just interested in the same thing?

The only time merging accounts happens is at the request of the user.

Comment: I very much like that policy (user request only), and I'm very much happy that these aren't sock puppets. To clarify again, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/revisions/62182/3, especially considering the edit title, is imho pretty clear in that Man and user.... share the same brain.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yup, sometimes that happens. Thanks for raising it, it's worth discussion.

Comment: I believe such a double faced user should already be connecting through proxies or VPNs to hide himself ? I don't know if the site allows VPN connection though...

Comment: @Fat32 Sure, they could do that. However, the system has flagged no abuses by the two users, apart from the slightly collusive behaviour noticed by Marcus.